# The type or namespace name 'OracleClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: c#, reference, oracleclient, system.data, system.data.oracleclient

When trying to run my code, I receive the following error:

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'OracleClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have included references to `System.Data.dll` and `System.Data.OracleClient.dll`, but I am still getting this error.

The error is being caused by the line `using System.Data.OracleClient` in my namespace declaration.

Comment: Okay. My answer doesn't match now that you've editted, and was just telling you what you already know. I'd first look at the properties of the references and make sure they pointed to the correct file, and for the corresponding version of .NET if there is more than one runtime on the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `using System.Data.OracleClient` directive means that that namespace should be considered when trying to determine what non-full names mean.

Adding a reference, means you add a reference to a given assembly, in this case System.Data.OracleClient.dll. From VisualStudio, SharpDevelop or MonoDevelop you will see a references folder in the project explorer view. Right click and "Add Reference" (VisualStudio and SharpDevelop) or "Edit References" (MonoDevelop), and add in System.Data.OracleClient.dll

If using nant you'll need to edit your nant script.

Assemblies and namespaces overlap, but aren't quite the same. The reference means you can use e.g. `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader` because the project now knows what assembly the code for that lives in. The `using` directive means you need only type `OracleDataReader`. There tends to be a heavy match between assemblies and namespaces because that makes life easier for everyone, but there are both times when an assembly has classes from more than one namespace, and when a namespace is split over more than one assembly. A classic example is that mscorlib has a lot of classes from `System`, `System.Collections`, `System.IO` etc. that you couldn't really hope to build a .NET project without (including some that .NET uses itself), while System.dll has a bunch more from exactly the same namespaces that you could feasibly get by without using (but you still will 99% of the time).

Unless you're writing an absolutely massive library though, with thousands of classes covering overlapping use-cases, your own assemblies should work with a single namespace - or at most a single one with some other namespaces within that one, like `JaredksGreatCode` having `JaredksGreatCode.UserInterface` within it - per single DLL.

Comment: I have already added the reference to the System.Data.OracleClient.dll and it shows up in my references folder (I'm using Visual Studio 2010).  The error still occurs.

Comment: Does the tick mean my comment helped you find the issue? (If nothing else, I like to know people aren't still stuck on something, also adding a bit more to the answer could help the next person).

Comment: This resolved the error I was getting with the `using System.Data.OracleClient` line.

Comment: I have read through the answer but it didn't resolve my issue.I'm using system.data.OracleClient to access  oracle db.Now the  oracleclient in the system.data is showing a warning.

Comment: @Sribin then maybe ask a question?

Comment: There was an another error which was not related to the  oracle  which in turn shows all the  oracleclient error.Once I resolved the other error ,the oracle error suppressed by itself.I guess it is time to use some other data access packages I'm getting the warning as it is obselete.But I dont have much idea about any other-I'm pretty new to oracle.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

Visual Studio --> WEBSITE --> Add Reference... --> Framework --> **System.Data.OracleClient** [check this option]

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a reference to the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`, and then I had to manually associate all the references to `OracleClient.blahblah` with 
`Oracle.DataAccess.Client.blahblah`.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference into your web config file as shown below. This works for me.

---

```
<!--REFERENCES-->
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score -3):

You add reference on `System.Data.OracleClient.dll`.